# Designing a RESTful Application on Netty

Tags: rest, netty

I would like my services which based on Netty to be RESTful. Is anyone experienced with a good library which I can use in order to fulfill that requirement?

Comment: Any reason for Netty rather than Jetty? Usually RESTful means HTTP as the transport these days.

Comment: The server should support Comet. From what I read, Netty is doing better that Jetty with serving Comet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used restexpress in the past. Its based on netty..

https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress

Comment: Hi, can you share your experience of using it? mostly in the performance perspective.

Comment: Well it was really straight forward to use and worked very well even on high scale. So I think there is nothing more to say ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is based on Jetty, but take a look at [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/)

```
public class FirstServerResource extends ServerResource {  

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
      // Create the HTTP server and listen on port 8182  
      new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, FirstServerResource.class).start();  
   }

   @Get  
   public String toString() {  
      return "hello, world";  
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite late to answer this question.

In my opinion [Play 2](https://www.playframework.com/) can be used for this.

Play framework usage **Netty** internally.
It is much like a mvc framework ecosystem.
I don't know whether it will be a overkill or not to use for only rest api creation but It provides non-blocking io, stateless and lots of other good features.

You can also check [Async http client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). It is based on Netty.